# eventDrop with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, fullcalendar

this is the part of my javascript code that uses fullcalendar:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.i-checks').iCheck({
        checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-green',
        radioClass: 'iradio_square-green',
    });

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        weekNumbers: true,
        eventLimit: true,
        editable: true,               
        events: '/Service/GetEventSources/',
        eventDrop: function (event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Service/ChangeEvent/',
                dataType: 'POST',
                data: {
                    id: event.id,
                    start: event.start,
                    end: event.end
                },
            });
        },
    });
});
</script>
```

This is the C# part, where i want to do a database update in my ASP.NET MVC
Web Application:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult ChangeEvent(int id, DateTime start, DateTime end)
{

    return Json(new
    {
        id =id,
        start = start.ToString("s"),
        end = end.ToString("s")
    }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I am using this bundle configuration in my C# Web App:

```
// fullCalendar styles
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/plugins/fullCalendarStyles").Include(
"~/Content/plugins/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css"));

// fullCalendar 
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/plugins/fullCalendar").Include(
"~/Scripts/plugins/fullcalendar/moment.min.js",
"~/Scripts/plugins/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js",
"~/Scripts/plugins/fullcalendar/lang/de.js"));
```

I downloaded those files today (08.04.2016) so they are up to date.

The post function 'ChangeEvent' in the 'Service' controller is never called - instead i get the following Error (from Chrome Debug mode):
[Google Debug View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6YM1.png)

Does anyone know, what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer the question myself!
The problem was the javascript part. the start and end properties of the event
had to be used with format(). Now everything works:

```
eventDrop: function (event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Service/ChangeEvent/',
            dataType: 'POST',
            data: {
                id: event.id,
                start: event.start.format(),
                end: event.end.format()
            },
        });
    },
```